# Solve for "$x$" when, tan(x) = csc(x), and Domain of $x$ is $(-\pi ,\pi)$ .

Tags: trigonometry

I solved it and get four answers, but the book gives only two: $\pm 0.905$ radian. Since the domain is  $(-\pi ,\pi)$, I thought there would be two more values. I checked with the calculator, and the other two values check out. They are $\pm 2.237$ radian. Am I wrong?
Thank you.
The problem is from Demana, Kennedy, Precalculus, 5th Edition, Page 386, Problem No. 43. I am doing self-study as a returning student.

Comment: I think I found out why the book gave only two solutions. The angles have to be either in the first or third quadrants, precisely because tan(x) and csc(x) have to have the same sign. Third and fourth quadrant values won't do, since in those quadrants, tan(x) and csc(x) values will have the opposite signs. Am I right?

Comment: Your logic is right. I will use short hand. If not clear I shall make it long hand.
$$ \dfrac{s}{c} =\dfrac{1}{s} ,\, s^2 = c, \,\, c^2 + c-1= = 0 $$
$$ \cos(x)= \dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2} $$ 
related to the Golden Ratio
Positive sign lands $x$ in first and fourth quadrants, negative sign  lands $x$ in second and third quadrants.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the fast response. Now I can go in peace, knowing that not all my brain cells are dried up.:-)

Comment: Welcome. With maths all will help to make them all wet.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\dfrac1{\sin x}\iff\cos x=\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$$

$$\iff\cos^2x+\cos x-1=0\implies\cos x=?$$

But $-1\le\cos x\le1$

Comment: You are faster than I!

Comment: You edited and now have the wrong sign on the linear term.

Comment: @Dr.MV, Sorry. Thanks for your observation

Comment: No worry ... minus signs get the better of all of us on occasion.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan x=\csc x$$ $$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{1}{\sin x}$$ $$\sin^2 x=\cos x$$
$$1-\cos^2 x=\cos x$$

> $$\cos^2 x+\cos x-1=0$$ 
>   $$\cos x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{(1)^2-4(1)(-1)}}{2(1)}=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$
>   $$\cos x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\ \ \vee \ \ \cos x=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
>   Can you take it from here?

Comment: That is not correct.  The sign on the linear term is $+1$

Comment: Hi Harish: thanks a lot. I went a bit different route, with sine functions. Yes, I could proceed with the cosine function as you just posted.

Comment: I agree with Dr MV. It cannot have imaginary solution. The first attempt was right.

Comment: Yes, DR MV. That was a quick catch. It takes so little to goof up a simple problem! As mentioned in my earlier comment to Harsih, I used sine function and went that route. But cosine would save time.:-)

Comment: @Dr MV, Yes, I did. I have labelled the edit

Comment: Great! Then +1 ..